# How to resolve You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0 in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an old project in Asp.NET-4.0. Then I just upgraded it from ASP.NET-4.0 TO 4.8

**I got this error:**

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'List<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
```

Some parts of my code are highlighted.

**Web.config is shown below:**

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: if you don't upgrade, and build the project using .net 4.0, does it build and run ok? (I mean, it goes without saying, that you no doubt have a working project that builds for .net 4.0, right?? - you would not leave that whopper of a detail out of your post, would you?